# Pyspark filter rows based on constant value

Tags: dataframe, filter, pyspark, aws-glue

```
+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
|     part_no|prod_week| daily_qty|lineoffdate|
+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
|019990616100|   202004| 000000000| 2020-01-23|
|019990616100|   202004| 000000000| 2020-01-24|
|019990616100|   202004| 000000000| 2020-01-25|
|019990616100|   202005| 000000000| 2020-01-26|
|019990616100|   202005| 000000000| 2020-01-27|
|019990616100|   202005| 000000001| 2020-01-28|
|019990616100|   202005| 000000000| 2020-01-29|
|019990616100|   202005| 000000000| 2020-01-30|
|019990616100|   202005| 000000000| 2020-01-31|
|019990616100|   202005| 000000000| 2020-02-01|
|019990616100|   202006| 000000000| 2020-02-02|
|019990616100|   202006| 000000000| 2020-02-03|
|019990616100|   202006| 000000000| 2020-02-04|
|019990616100|   202006| 000000000| 2020-02-05|
|019990616100|   202006| 000000000| 2020-02-06|
|019990616100|   202006| 000000000| 2020-02-07|
|019990616100|   202006| 000000000| 2020-02-08|
|019990616100|   202007| 000000000| 2020-02-09|
|019990616100|   202007| 000000000| 2020-02-10|
|019990616100|   202007| 000000000| 2020-02-11|
+------------+---------+----------+-----------+
```

I would like to drop or filter the rows  to exclude daily_qty with value '000000000'.
daily_qty is of type string.
Tried the below combinations but the filtering does not seems to work at all. Can you someone please help me where I am going wrong

```
ds1 =  ds.filter(F.col('daily_qty') != '000000000')
#ds1 =  ds.filter(F.col('daily_qty') != F.lit('000000000'))
#ds1=ds.filter(~F.col('daily_qty').isin(['000000000']))
```

Thanks,
Aruna

Comment: Shouldn't you be using just `F.col('daily_qty')`?

Comment: Yes I corrected the question.

Comment: `ds1 =  ds.filter(F.col('daily_qty') != '000000000')` this works for the example you have provided in my system